# Nested Loop in Python Not Working

Tags: python

I would like to have this output:

```
* * * 
2 2 2 
4 4 4  
6 6 6 
8 8 8
```

I cannot get it and I've tried many ways, but my code doesn't seem to work. Here is my current code:

```
for row in range(3):
    print ("*", end = " ")
    print ()
    for col in range(2,9,2):
        print (row, end = " ")
        print ()
print()
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you are using `end` in your print statements.  Keep in mind that you must print line by line.  There is no way to print column by column.

```
print('* * *')
for i in range(2, 9, 2):
    print('{0} {0} {0}'.format(i))
```

For further explanation about the `{0}`s, look up the `format` method for strings: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
print('* * *') 
for col in range(2,9,2):
    print (*[col]*3, sep=' ')
```

To be more clear.

```
>>> a = 2
>>> [a]
[2]
>>> [a]*3
[2, 2, 2]
>>> print(*[a]*3, sep=' ')  # equal to print(a, a, a, sep=' ')
2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you only have one row that contains `* * *` which can be printed at the very top, outside of any loops:

`print('* * *')`

Next, you would need to start your loop from values `2` (inclusive) and `9` (exclusive) in steps of `2`:

`for col in range(2,9,2):`

You don't need to use any `end` keyword here, so just printing the row multiple times is sufficient:

`print('{0} {0} {0}'.format(i))`

So the final block of code looks like:

```
print('* * *')
for row in range(2,9,2):
    print('{0} {0} {0}'.format(row))
```

You don't need to add another `print()`, `print` already ends with a newline anyway.